# Javascript Reference - HTML DOM Style height Property and return to first style height

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello guys it's simple to fix who knows js. So I have code to change my style of height on first click but I want when user clicks next time to return the first style height.

So here is code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">test</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {<!--   w  w  w .ja  v  a  2s  .c om-->
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.height = "50px";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this works fine on one click but I want when I click next time to return me on first height

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why is there an html comment in the JavaScript?

Comment: Toggle a class...

Comment: @epascarello it's just one button, so when you run code snippet you will see. I put everything together to make this simple

Comment: Code is easier if you just [toggle a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)...

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you should just create a css class and toggle it on-click.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.my-height { height: 50px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="this.classList.toggle('my-height')">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```